# discrete expected number of trials before success

Tags: probability

A directory on a computer’s hard disk contains 12 files, 3 of which have viruses. If a file with a 
virus is selected, the virus is detected and another file is then selected. Find the expected 
number of files that must be selected in order to get a virus-free file. This is without replacement so 12 files in total to work with (3 virus, 9 clean)

Is this the correct way to do this problem? 
1 + (n/(b+1)) where b is # of clean files and n is # of viruses

The answer I believe to be between 1 and 4, your best and worst case scenarios. 
Using that formula I get 1.3 but I'm not sure it's correct.

Comment: The formula fails the simplest consistency check: If there are no clean files, the expected value should be undefined (or $+\infty$). Your formula gives $1+n$...

Answer (score 0):

\begin{cases}
\Pr(\text{1st is virus-free)}) & = \dfrac9{12} \\[6pt]
\Pr(\text{1st is infected & 2nd is virus-free}) & = \dfrac 3{12}\cdot\dfrac 9 {11} \\[6pt]
\Pr(\text{1st & 2nd are infected and 3rd is virus-free}) & = \dfrac 3 {12}\cdot\dfrac 2 {11}\cdot\dfrac 9 {10} \\[8pt]
\Pr(\text{1st, 2nd, & 3rd are infected}) & = \dfrac 3{12}\cdot\dfrac 2 {11}\cdot\dfrac 1 {10}
\end{cases}

In the last case, the fourth one is necessarily clean.

So $1$ times the first probability plus $2$ times the second plus $3$ times the third plus $4$ times the fourth is the expected number needed to get a virus-free file.

Comment: So if I'm not mistaken that does indeed equal 1.3 if you round? Your way makes way more sense intuitively.

Comment: I'm getting the following, but you should check it: $1\cdot\dfrac 3 4 + 2\cdot\dfrac 1 4 \cdot\dfrac 9 {11} + 3\cdot\dfrac 1 4\cdot\dfrac 9 {55} + 4\cdot\dfrac 1 4\cdot\dfrac 1{55}$ $= \dfrac 3 4 + \dfrac 9 {22} + \dfrac 3 {220} + \dfrac 1 {55}$ $= \dfrac{165+90+3+4}{220} = \dfrac{262}{220}=\dfrac{131}{110}$ $= 1.19090909\ldots\,$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

We use the notation of the post, with $n$ the number of viruses and $b$ the number of clean files. Of course we assume that $b\ge 1$. Let the viruses be labelled $v_1$ to $v_n$

For $i=1$ to $n$, let $X_i=1$ if the  virus labelled $v_i$ comes before any clean file, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number of trials up to and including the first clean file is $1+X_1+\cdots+X_n$. By the linearity of expectation our expected number of trials is 
$$1+E(X_1)+E(X_2)+E(X_n).$$
The probability that the virus labelled $v_i$ comes before any clean file is $\frac{1}{1+b}$. We conclude that the required expectation is $1+\frac{n}{b+1}$.

**Remark:** Alternately, one can first find the *distribution* of the number of trials. But the method of *indicator random variables*  that we used is more efficient.